# Outside faucet repair

Tags: plumbing, faucet

do I need to replace the entire faucet or just install a handle?  It looks corroded inside.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That really looks like debris, not corrosion.

Comment: Do you have any of the parts that were removed?

Comment: No. We recently moved into this house and this is how it was.

Comment: Is the valve stem broken off, I can't quite tell. I would turn the water off and remove the packing nut unscrew the stem and take it to a plumbing store, a new stem and a fresh packing would be much easier than replacing the entire faucet.

Comment: That photo hurts my eyes, but we might be seeing the torn up stem packing.

Comment: If one can determine the make/model of the existing faucet, most outdoor faucets have parts kits available which may include the missing parts. This is because it is a real pain to replace. I used a couple kits to repair leaky faucets last year. https://amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtools&field-keywords=Woodford+Repair+Kit

Comment: I would bet the water is already turned off inside someplace. Hard to imagine it not leaking like that.

Comment: Is there a logo on the side?

Comment: Upvote for providing good photos.  This is a very well-formed question.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you are missing some parts of a faucet or valve, you will have to replace the whole thing. You should not expect the core from one faucet to fit the body of another. Each manufacturer, usually for each model, makes the body, core screw, compression nut, handle, etc. to fit together in a unique way.

The only dimensional standard is the soft washer and the seat that it presses against, and even these are made in several sizes and materials.

Sometimes you can get lucky and find in a hardware store a new faucet of the exact same make and model as the one you're trying to fix. Then you can take it apart and use some of the pieces for your repair, which saves the labor of replacing the entire thing. But you're not going to be able to buy parts for a faucet or valve, except for the rubber washer.

Comment: Exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's time to change it out to me.